# ctypes and PySide

Tags: python, qt4, ctypes, pyside

I'm building an app with PySide, there's some image manipulation that needs to be done and using Python code for this is way too slow. Therefore I hacked out a .dll file that will do it for me. The function definition is as follows:

```
   extern "C" {
QRectF get_image_slant(QImage *img, float slantangle, float offset) {
```

Now I can load this function in via ctypes. But I can't seem to get ctypes to accept a QImage.  I tried calling it like this:

```
ext.get_image_slant(QImage(), 0, 0)
```

And the reply I get is:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1
```

I tired casting the QImage to a c_void_p and it doesn't like that either. From what I can tell QImage() in python should map exactly to a QImage * in C, but Python doesn't seem to understand that..

Is there any way to force the casting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ctypes` for C++ [isn't working very well](http://blog.vrplumber.com/index.php?/archives/197-Ctypes-for-C++-is-going-to-be-a-pain-due-to-politics-Bothering-language-creators-is-fun....html), I would recommend using PySide's own wrapper - [Shiboken](http://www.pyside.org/docs/shiboken/). They actually use it to wrap the Qt libs themselves. Since your code deals with Qt object, this seems like the perfect choice for you.